# Why DateTime.Now returns some 2 years back DateTime?

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin

IDE: Visual Studio Community 2015

### Xamarin Android Mobile Project

I try to get the current date like I have always been doing:

**DateTime.Now**

but it returns some date from 2 years back.

It should return December 08, 2016 - but I get {1/5/2014 12:00:00 AM} which is January the 5th of 2014.

If you go to definition for the DateTime it takes you to that class that has the following reference to **MonoAndroid mscorlib.dll file**

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll**

Normally it would work with NetFramework DLL file located at

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll**

Tried to debug it - get the same 2014 date during the runtime.

Note: I am a 100% sober ; )

So the MonoAndroid mscorlib.dll messes with it then, right?

Will investigate & get back to you on this thought.

PC: Current PC Date is December 08, 2016

Comment: what is the clock of your Android emulator set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android emulator has it's own clock - it's not necessarily sync'd to the host's system clock.